# Проблема с Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Всем привет. Пишу проект с computer vision. Буквально несколько дней назад всё работало. Ничего не менял, решил зайти и потестить на других данных. Появились следующие ошибки. 
Скачивание API:

```
!apt-get install protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk
!pip install Cython
!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
!cd models/research; protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
!cd models/research; export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim; python 
object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

Ошибка при скачивании:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 23, in <module>    
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", 
line 22, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import box_predictor_builder
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/builders/box_predictor_builder.py", 
line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.predictors import convolutional_box_predictor
  File "/content/models/research/object_detection/predictors/convolutional_box_predictor.py", line 23, in <module> 
    slim = tf.contrib.slim
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

При вызове

```
# Загружаем новую модель в память
model_file_name =  model_name + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(model_file_name, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-7df3652d50e9> in <module>()
      2 detection_graph = tf.Graph()
      3 with detection_graph.as_default():
----> 4   od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      5   with tf.gfile.GFile(model_file_name, 'rb') as fid:
      6     serialized_graph = fid.read()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphDef'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса